# Hibernate java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans

I've been working through the [Hibernate Tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html#01) provided by Netbeans but whenever I tried running the program I end up with a `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`. Anyone have any ideas about what's wrong?

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at dvdrental.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:29)
    at dvdrental.FilmHelper.<init>(FilmHelper.java:18)
    at dvdrental.FilmController.<init>(FilmController.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:438)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:186)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:257)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:80)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:135)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:457)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1850)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:245)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at dvdrental.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:25)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:230)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:242)
    ... 73 more
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
package dvdrental;

import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

/**
 * Hibernate Utility class with a convenient method to get Session Factory
 * object.
 *
 * @author andre_000
 */
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
            // config file.
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log the exception. 
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

FilmHelper.java

```
package dvdrental;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Query;
/**
 *
 * @author andre_000
 */
public class FilmHelper {
      Session session = null;
      public FilmHelper() {
        this.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
      }

      public List getFilmTitles(int startID, int endID) {
        List<Film> filmList = null;
        try {
          org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
          Query q = session.createQuery("from Film as film where film.filmId between '"+startID+"' and '"+endID+"'");
          filmList = (List<Film>) q.list();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return filmList;
      }

      public List getActorsByID(int filmId) {
        List<Actor> actorList = null;
        try {
          org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
          Query q = session.createQuery("from Actor as where actor.actorId in (select filmActor.actor.actorId from FilmActor as filmActor where filmActor.film.filmId='" + filmId + "')");
          actorList = (List<Actor>) q.list();
        } catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return actorList;
      }

      public Category getCategoryByID(int filmId) {
        List<Category> categoryList = null;
        try {
          org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
          Query q = session.createQuery("from Category as category where category.categoryId in (select filmCat.category.categoryId from FilmCategory as filmCat where filmCat.film.filmId='" + filmId + "')");
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return categoryList.get(0);
      }

      public Film getFilmByID(int filmId) {
        Film film  = null;
        try {
          org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
          Query q = session.createQuery("from Film as film where film.filmId=" + filmId);
          film = (Film) q.uniqueResult();
        } catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return film;
      }

      public String getLangByID(int langId) {
        Language language = null;
        try {
          org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
          Query q = session.createQuery("from Language as lang where lang.languageId=" + langId);
          language = (Language) q.uniqueResult();
        } catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return language.getName();
      }

}
```

FilmController.java

```
package dvdrental;

import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.model.DataModel;
import javax.faces.model.ListDataModel;

/**
 *
 * @author andre_000
 */
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class FilmController {

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of FilmController
     */
     int startId;
     int endId;
     DataModel filmTitles;
     FilmHelper helper;
     private int recordCount = 1000;
     private int pageSize = 10;
     private Film current;
     private int selectedItemIndex;
    public FilmController() {
      helper = new FilmHelper();
      startId = 1;
      endId = 10;
    }
    public FilmController(int startId, int endId) {
      helper = new FilmHelper();
      this.startId = startId;
      this.endId = endId;
    }
    public Film getSelected() {
      if(current == null) {
        current = new Film();
        selectedItemIndex = -1;
      }
      return current;
    }

    public DataModel getFilmTitles() {
      if(filmTitles == null) {
        filmTitles = new ListDataModel(helper.getFilmTitles(startId, endId));
      }
      return filmTitles;
    }

    void recreateModel() {
      filmTitles = null;
    }

    public boolean isHasNextPage() {
      if(endId + pageSize <= recordCount)
        return true;
      return false;
    }

    public boolean isHasPreviousPage() {
      if(startId-pageSize > 0)
        return true;
      return false;
    }

    public String next() {
      startId = endId+1;
      endId += pageSize;
      recreateModel();
      return "index";
    }
    public String previous() {
      startId -= pageSize;
      endId -= pageSize;
      recreateModel();
      return "index";
    }

    public int getPageSize() {
      return pageSize;
    }

    public String prepareView() {
      current = (Film) getFilmTitles().getRowData();
      return "browse";
    }
    public String prepareList() {
      recreateModel();
      return "index";
    }
    public String getLanguage() {
      int langID = current.getLanguageByLanguageId().getLanguageId().intValue();
      String language = helper.getLangByID(langID);
      return language;
    }
    public String getActors() {
      List actors = helper.getActorsByID(current.getFilmId());
      StringBuffer totalCast = new StringBuffer();
      for (int i = 0; i < actors.size(); i++) {
        Actor actor = (Actor) actors.get(i);
        totalCast.append(actor.getFirstName());
        totalCast.append(" ");
        totalCast.append(actor.getLastName());
        totalCast.append(" ");
      }
      return totalCast.toString();
    }

    public String getCategory() {
      Category category = helper.getCategoryByID(current.getFilmId());
      return category.getName();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    Could not load requested class : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

It probably means you don't put the MySQL's driver in classpath.

So, [download](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) the jar and add it.

Obs:
For Glassfish, like the tutorial you following, put the `mysql-connector-java-*-bin.jar` in the `yourdomain/lib` directory of your installation.

Comment: or use Maven: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.34

Answer (score 0):

The translator factory class used in Hibernate 4 is bundled with the IDE.

So,
-->Click Add under the Miscellaneous Properties node and select hibernate.query.factory_class in the Property Name dropdown list.

-->**Type** **org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory** as the Property Value. 
***//do not select **org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory** as the Property Value in the dialog box.***

Answer (score 0):

It can be that on your hibernate configuration file mapping you have something like this `<mapping class="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />` so this means that when the session is about to be created,it load that class name of which that is not a class ,it is driver name for mysql.

Try changing it to `<mapping class="packageName.ClassName" />` the class name is the one annotated as an entity.